# Umbraco7 Navigation: add class to parent UL

Tags: razor, umbraco7

Using Umbraco7 I have made a PartialView based on Umbracos Sitemap.
I have managed to add a "current" class to the current `<li>` but I would like to target the parent UL aswell.

A quick overview:

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <ul> <-This guy needs a Current/Parent Class
       <li class="current">
          Here you are
       </li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

**Partial view:**

```
    @inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@{ var selection = CurrentPage.Site(); }

    @Traverse(selection)


@helper Traverse(dynamic node)
{
var maxLevelForSitemap = 3;

var selection = node.Children.Where("Visible").Where("Level <= " + maxLevelForSitemap);

if (selection.Any())
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in selection)
        {
           string cssClass = @item.Id != CurrentPage.Id ? "" : "current";

            <li class="@cssClass">
                <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>

                @Traverse(item)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more details about which class this ul tag needs? Is it only for the ul which contains the current li?

Comment: Hallo Mivaweb, when I access a page inside the UL and it gives a postback, my menu collapse. If I have a class on the previous UL (parent to current class) then I can target the UL with CSS and give it a display:block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a small jquery script for this that gets executed each time the page loads or when a postback occures:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.current').closest('ul').addClass('active');
});
```

This will get the current li and search for the closest ul ( parent ) and add the class `active`.

Comment: It's actually a good solution Mivaweb :) I would like to make it work inside the partial view but this works just fine, cheers!